# Loading lib from plugin - cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a plugin and inside the plugin I have a Lib folder.
Like this:

`Lib/Billing/CMS/CMS.php`

How can I use the CMS class inside `CMS.php` on my controller? Not my plugin controller, but a controller on my application.

EDIT: Cake version is 2.3

Comment: You should always mention the cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

So, from your short information one can only guess...
Your plugin is "Billing"?

Your files are

```
APP/Plugin/Billing/Lib/CMS/CMS.php (class CMS)
APP/Plugin/Billing/Lib/Billing.php (class Billing)
```

You include classes always the same, using App::uses().
Then its

```
App::uses('CMS', 'Billing.CMS'); // Filename, Plugin.Package
```

and

```
App::uses('Billing', 'Billing.Lib'); // Lib as package namespace here due to lack of a proper one
```

I do not have to point out, that you need to load your plugin first, right?
Using CakePlugin::load()/loadAll()

Comment: The plugin is called Billing. Tried this approach - the plugin is being loaded. Still nothing :(

Comment: Can you confirm that the path as I guessed is correct? The class is called CMS.php? Note the casing.

Comment: Hey @mark, 
I think my problem is that the CMS class extends a Billing class.
The full path would be

`Plugin \ Billing \ Lib \ Billing.php` AND
`Plugin \ Billing \ Lib \ CMS \ CMS.php`

The CMS class extends Billing.php.

And thanks for the help. New to cake.

Comment: Then you need to App::uses() the classes you use at the top of the file. According to documenation and my example above (slightly corrected then).

Comment: That's how I am trying:

`App::uses('Billing', 'Billing.Lib');
App::uses('CMS', 'Billing.Lib/CMS');
$foo = new CMS();`

Does not work. Billing is an abstract class. I though because it is already being used inside CMS class you would not need to App::uses it. If I create a dummy class in the same path not extending from anything, then it works fine.

Comment: Lib is only a namespace as standalone (and should not be used as one).

Comment: Hey @mark, I can move the Billing.php class to a BaseClass folder - and even rename it as BaseClass. What I want to know is how do (with an example code if possible) I get around it? I am almost ditching the base class and forget about inheritance... Thanks heaps.